# Why is "java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptExceptio" called when caling multiple groupBy with pyspark?

Tags: memory, group-by, pyspark, shuffle

I am running a pyspark job (python 3.5, spark 2.1, java8) in yarn-client mode from an edge node with spark2-submit. The job succed, the result dataframe is written on HDFS and seems correct (we didn't find yet any error with the data in such dataframe).

The issue is that I see a lot (6'000) ERROR messages and I would like to understand what is wrong and if this impact or not the final dataframe.

All ERROR messages looks like this one:

```
18/06/01 14:08:36 INFO codegen.CodeGenerator: Code generated in 45.712788 ms

18/06/01 14:08:37 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 33.0 in stage 34.0 (TID 2312). 4600 bytes result sent to driver

18/06/01 14:08:37 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 117.0 in stage 34.0 (TID 2316). 3801 bytes result sent to driver

18/06/01 14:08:40 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Got assigned task 2512

18/06/01 14:08:40 INFO executor.Executor: Running task 190.1 in stage 34.0 (TID 2512)

18/06/01 14:08:40 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 28 non-empty blocks out of 193 blocks

18/06/01 14:08:40 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 5 remote fetches in 1 ms

18/06/01 14:08:40 INFO executor.Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 190.1 in stage 34.0 (TID 2512)

18/06/01 14:08:40 ERROR storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter: Uncaught exception while reverting partial writes to file /...../yarn/nm/usercache/../appcache/application_xxxx/blockmgr-xxxx/temp_shuffle_xxxxx

java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException

            at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
            at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.truncate(FileChannelImpl.java:372)

            at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.revertPartialWritesAndClose(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:212)

            at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.stop(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:238)

            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:102)

            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)

            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)

            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)

            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The ERROR start after quite some feture engineering (select, groupby ..) and I see the ERROR when adding these lines:

```
df = (df.groupby('x','y')
        .agg(func.sum('x').alias('x_sum'))
        .groupby('y')
        .agg(func.mean('y').alias('py_sum_avg')))
```

So I guess the of the data shuffle is triggered by groupBy.

I first thought it was an issue with memory so I added much more memory and overhead memory for the driver and executor without a real success (this is what you can find in some other thread). In the code I have other groupBy and it seems it is causing some issue at this stage.

I also see that it could be related to too many files open or if the disk is full but the ERROR messages is a bit different in these 2 cases.

I am quite new in pysaprk so I am looking to advice to debug such issue.

How can I find what is the reason why is called `java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException` ? I guess this is the reason that trigger `ERROR storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter`. Is this correct ? Is it trigger by `Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 190` If this is a standard process to have some tasks killed why is this triggering ERRORs ? Can I get some hint by looking at the Sprak UI (I see that some task were killed).Can I get more info from the traceback ?

How can fixed these issues ? Any suggestion how to proceed to debug such things ? I am not sure how to proceed to debug this issue and where to look at (memory, issue in the pysaprk code, issue with the setup of the cluster or of my spark params)

I am working on an Hadoop Data Lake with Cloudera CDH 5.8.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with using spark.speculation in Spark 2.1 which I am using. 
The related upstream bug is SPARK-19293. The exception stack trace in my situation is slightly different than the one in SPARK-19293. Putting

> --conf spark.speculation=false

and the ERROR are gone in my test